# Select from MySQL, split and insert into <td></td>

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

I have table "att" in mysql like this:

```
datetime                   userid     startorend
2022-10-25 10:00:00     1          0
2022-10-25 14:30:00     44         0
2022-10-25 11:00:00     1          1 
2022-10-25 14:40:00     44         1
```

So have 2 users which start and end their job.

Select works fine but it shows me wrong:

```
Name     starttime               endtime
user1    2022-10-25 10:00:00     
user1    2022-10-25 11:00:00
user2    2022-10-25 14:30:00    
2022-10-25 14:40:00
```

Need to show data in html table. I want to show it like:

```
Name     starttime               endtime
user1    2022-10-25 10:00:00     2022-10-25 11:00:00
user2    2022-10-25 14:30:00     2022-10-25 14:40:00
```

How can I achieve this?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM att WHERE date(att.starttime) = CURDATE() ORDER BY userid ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if (!$result) {
  die("Problém" . mysqli_error($conn));
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $userid = $row['userid'];
  $time= $row['datetime'];

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $userid. " " . $name . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $time . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: The columns in the table you are trying to echo do not seem to line up with the expected query output.  You should fix your question.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($$conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Comment: That's a job for SQL, not for PHP. You need to use a JOIN and find the end time.

Comment: You'd join 2 copies of your table.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT userid, t1.`datetime`, t2.`datetime`
FROM att t1
JOIN att t2 USING (userid)
WHERE !t1.startorend
  AND t2.startorend
-- AND DATE(t1.starttime) = CURRENT_DATE
-- AND DATE(t2.starttime) = CURRENT_DATE
```

I do not see the source for username... another table must be used.

The query assumes that there exists only one income and one outcome per day in the table.

---

> it doesn't work fine for me. no results there. – sover

You do something wrongly.

```
CREATE TABLE att (`datetime` DATETIME, userid INT, startorend BOOLEAN);
INSERT INTO att VALUES
('2022-10-25 10:00:00',     1,          0),
('2022-10-25 14:30:00',     44,         0),
('2022-10-25 11:00:00',     1,          1),
('2022-10-25 14:40:00',     44,         1);
SELECT * FROM att;
```

| datetime | userid | startorend |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-25 10:00:00 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-10-25 14:30:00 | 44 | 0 |
| 2022-10-25 11:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-10-25 14:40:00 | 44 | 1 |

```
SELECT userid, t1.`datetime`, t2.`datetime`
FROM att t1
JOIN att t2 USING (userid)
WHERE !t1.startorend
  AND t2.startorend
-- AND DATE(t1.starttime) = CURRENT_DATE
-- AND DATE(t2.starttime) = CURRENT_DATE
```

| userid | datetime | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-25 10:00:00 | 2022-10-25 11:00:00 |
| 44 | 2022-10-25 14:30:00 | 2022-10-25 14:40:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2IzH629g)

Comment: thank you, but seems it doesn't work fine for me. no results there.

Comment: @sover Fiddle added. Check yourself.

Comment: Ok, I made some changes, so see this please: https://pastebin.com/RJ8A4hWg

Comment: @sover I do not work with HTML and PHP.